# Need a Mono-compatible WinForms docking library

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, dockpanel

I've been looking for a Visual Studio-like docking library for WinForms, but the two most popular and complete options (WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking and the MagicLibrary) both use P/Invokes extensively, so I can't use them in Mono.

The best I can manage so far is toggling a Panel from being hosted by the main form or by a toolwindow that's made on the spot by setting the control's Parent. This is nowhere near the functionality I'm looking for, as I'm sure you can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for a while and have found none, most WinForm dockpanel lib's use P/Invokes.

What platforms are you targeting?  You may have to checkout other GUI libs like GTK#.

Answer (score 1):

latest DockPanel Suite starts to support Mono, with drag and drop automatically disabled. It is difficult to rewrite the P/Invoke for other platforms, and hope one day that can be achieved,

http://dockpanelsuite.com